# Why am i getting error 'illegal start of type'

Tags: java, if-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExcerciseCJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);

        int user_age;
        System.out.print("Enter you're age");
        user_age = user_input.nextInt();

        if (user_age <= 10) {
            System.out.println("You are between 0 and 10");
        }else if (user_age > 10 && < 20) {   //<-(Error is showing on this line)
            System.out.println("You are between 11 and 20");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be `user_age > 10 && user_age< 20`

Comment: Despite years of java experience I still do this on occasion, it just feels natural somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
if (user_age > 10 && < 20)
```

with

```
if (user_age > 10 && user_age < 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the syntax is incorrect, Try this

```
else if (user_age > 10 && user_age < 20) {
```

How this executes ?

1. computes the first boolean statement `user_age > 10`
2. and the second statement `user_age < 20`
3. and performs `&&` using the two.

Thus in your case the second statement becomes `< 20` which ofcourse is syntactically incorrect as there is nothing to compare with 20.

Answer (score 0):

Its a syntactical error.

```
 else if (user_age > 10 && < 20){...}
```

It should be

```
 else if (user_age > 10 && user_age < 20){...}
                           ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (user_age > 10 && < 20)
```

Should be

```
else if (user_age > 10 && user_age < 20)
```

In regular mathematical term, you do this

```
6 > x > 2 , meaning x i greater than 2 or less than 6
```

In Java, you have separate each piece of logic

```
(user_age > 10 && user_age < 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (user_age > 10 && < 20)
```

with :

```
if (user_age > 10 && user_age < 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly specify what the comparison is to:

```
else if (user_age > 10 && user_age < 20) {
```

However, notice that you've already established that `user_age > 10` in the previous condition:

```
if (user_age <= 10) {
```

So you don't need to check it again:

```
if (user_age <= 10) {
    System.out.println("You are between 0 and 10");

} else if (user_age < 20) {
    // user_age was not <= 10, it must be > 10
    System.out.println("You are between 11 and 19");

} else {
    System.out.println("You are 20 or older");
}
```